# Seaborn tick labels not complete & not aligned to the graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a line chart based on 2 columns using seaborn from a dataframe imported as a .csv with pandas.

The data consists of ~97000 records across 19 years of timeframe.

**First part of the code:** (I assume the code directly below shouldn't contribute to the issue, but will list it just in case)

```
# use pandas to read CSV files and prepare the timestamp column for recognition
temporal_fires = pd.read_csv("D:/GIS/undergraduateThesis/data/fires_csv/mongolia/modis_2001-2019_Mongolia.csv")
temporal_fires = temporal_fires.rename(columns={"acq_date": "datetime"})

# recognize the datetime column from the data
temporal_fires["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(temporal_fires["datetime"])

# add a year column to the dataframe
temporal_fires["year"] = temporal_fires["datetime"].dt.year
temporal_fires['count'] = temporal_fires['year'].map(temporal_fires['year'].value_counts())
```

**The plotting part of the code:**

```
# plotting (seaborn)
plot1 = sns.lineplot(x="year",
                     y="count",
                     data=temporal_fires,
                     color='firebrick')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
plt.xlabel("Шаталт бүртгэгдсэн он", fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("Бүртгэгдсэн шаталтын тоо")
plt.title("2001-2019 он тус бүрт бүртгэгдсэн шаталтын график")
plt.xticks(fontsize=7.5, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(fontsize=7.5)
```

Python doesn't return any errors and does show the figure:
[image: Output of the above code]

... but (1) the labels are not properly aligned with the graph vertices and (2) I want the X label ticks to show each year instead of skipping some. For the latter, I did find a stackoverflow post, but it was for a heatmap, so I'm not sure how I'll advance in this case.

How do I align them properly and show all ticks?

Thank you.

Comment: try this: `plt.xlim(temporal_fires["year"].min(), temporal_fires["year"].max()`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, just in case anyone makes the same mistake.

The line

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: int(x)))
```

converted the X ticks on my plot to to its nearest number, but the original values stayed the same. The misalignment was because I had just *renamed* the "years" "2001.5" to "2001", not actually modifying the core data itself.

As for the label intervals, the addition of this line...

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(temporal_fires['year']), max(temporal_fires['year'])+1, 1.0))
```

...showed me all of the year values in the plot instead of skipping them.